# XElement.Descendants doesn't work with namespace

Tags: namespaces, xelement

I have a simple XML,

```
<S xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><H></H></S>
```

I want to find all "H" nodes.

```
XElement x = XElement.Parse("<S xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><H></H></S>");
IEnumerable<XElement> h = x.Descendants("H");
if (h != null)
{
}
```

But this code doesn't work. 
When I remove the namespace from S tag, the code works correctly.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with WPF, by the way...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your element has a namespace because `xmlns` effectively sets the *default* namespace for that element and its descendants. Try this instead:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
IEnumerable<XElement> h = x.Descendants(ns + "H");
```

Note that `Descendants` will *never* return null, so the condition at the end of your code is pointless.

If you want to find *all* `H` elements regardless of namespace, you could use:

```
var h = x.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "H");
```

Answer (score 8):

Just wanted to add to Jon's answer that you can get the namespace like this:

```
XNamespace ns = x.Name.Namespace
```

Then just use it like he proposed:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> h = x.Descendants(ns + "H");
```